# Getting additional information from IBM Watson Personal Insights - Python

Tags: python, ibm-watson, watson-personality-insights

I am sending information to IBM Watson personal insights. This file is about reviews from different users. I have a JSON file per user, and the identification of a user is stored in the id field (in this case the user 516):

```
{
  "contentItems": [
    {
      "content": "Some comments blablabla...",
      "contenttype": "text/plain",
      "id": 516,
      "language": "en"          
    }
  ]
}
```

According to the documentation, the required parameters are only "content", "contenttype".

I want to store information about the id of the user (again 516), but the response from IBM Watson it' not comming with the id. Do you know if is possible that Watson replies with such information? Or even if I pass additional information from the JSON input file (i.e. "Rating":"5"), is able to response with this additional information?

The response from Personal Insights

```
big5_agreeableness,facet_altruism,facet_cooperation,facet_modesty,facet_morality,facet_sympathy,facet_trust,big5_conscientiousness,facet_achievement_striving,facet_cautiousness,facet_dutifulness,facet_orderliness,facet_self_discipline,facet_self_efficacy,big5_extraversion,facet_activity_level,facet_assertiveness,facet_cheerfulness,facet_excitement_seeking,facet_friendliness,facet_gregariousness,big5_neuroticism,facet_anger,facet_anxiety,facet_depression,facet_immoderation,facet_self_consciousness,facet_vulnerability,big5_openness,facet_adventurousness,facet_artistic_interests,facet_emotionality,facet_imagination,facet_intellect,facet_liberalism,need_liberty,need_ideal,need_love,need_practicality,need_self_expression,need_stability,need_structure,need_challenge,need_closeness,need_curiosity,need_excitement,need_harmony,value_conservation,value_hedonism,value_openness_to_change,value_self_enhancement,value_self_transcendence,behavior_sunday,behavior_monday,behavior_tuesday,behavior_wednesday,behavior_thursday,behavior_friday,behavior_saturday,behavior_0000,behavior_0100,behavior_0200,behavior_0300,behavior_0400,behavior_0500,behavior_0600,behavior_0700,behavior_0800,behavior_0900,behavior_1000,behavior_1100,behavior_1200,behavior_1300,behavior_1400,behavior_1500,behavior_1600,behavior_1700,behavior_1800,behavior_1900,behavior_2000,behavior_2100,behavior_2200,behavior_2300,word_count,processed_language,big5_agreeableness_raw,facet_altruism_raw,facet_cooperation_raw,facet_modesty_raw,facet_morality_raw,facet_sympathy_raw,facet_trust_raw,big5_conscientiousness_raw,facet_achievement_striving_raw,facet_cautiousness_raw,facet_dutifulness_raw,facet_orderliness_raw,facet_self_discipline_raw,facet_self_efficacy_raw,big5_extraversion_raw,facet_activity_level_raw,facet_assertiveness_raw,facet_cheerfulness_raw,facet_excitement_seeking_raw,facet_friendliness_raw,facet_gregariousness_raw,big5_neuroticism_raw,facet_anger_raw,facet_anxiety_raw,facet_depression_raw,facet_immoderation_raw,facet_self_consciousness_raw,facet_vulnerability_raw,big5_openness_raw,facet_adventurousness_raw,facet_artistic_interests_raw,facet_emotionality_raw,facet_imagination_raw,facet_intellect_raw,facet_liberalism_raw,need_liberty_raw,need_ideal_raw,need_love_raw,need_practicality_raw,need_self_expression_raw,need_stability_raw,need_structure_raw,need_challenge_raw,need_closeness_raw,need_curiosity_raw,need_excitement_raw,need_harmony_raw,value_conservation_raw,value_hedonism_raw,value_openness_to_change_raw,value_self_enhancement_raw,value_self_transcendence_raw,big5_agreeableness_significant,facet_altruism_significant,facet_cooperation_significant,facet_modesty_significant,facet_morality_significant,facet_sympathy_significant,facet_trust_significant,big5_conscientiousness_significant,facet_achievement_striving_significant,facet_cautiousness_significant,facet_dutifulness_significant,facet_orderliness_significant,facet_self_discipline_significant,facet_self_efficacy_significant,big5_extraversion_significant,facet_activity_level_significant,facet_assertiveness_significant,facet_cheerfulness_significant,facet_excitement_seeking_significant,facet_friendliness_significant,facet_gregariousness_significant,big5_neuroticism_significant,facet_anger_significant,facet_anxiety_significant,facet_depression_significant,facet_immoderation_significant,facet_self_consciousness_significant,facet_vulnerability_significant,big5_openness_significant,facet_adventurousness_significant,facet_artistic_interests_significant,facet_emotionality_significant,facet_imagination_significant,facet_intellect_significant,facet_liberalism_significant,need_liberty_significant,need_ideal_significant,need_love_significant,need_practicality_significant,need_self_expression_significant,need_stability_significant,need_structure_significant,need_challenge_significant,need_closeness_significant,need_curiosity_significant,need_excitement_significant,need_harmony_significant,value_conservation_significant,value_hedonism_significant,value_openness_to_change_significant,value_self_enhancement_significant,value_self_transcendence_significant

0.033088390694386016,0.6521895549183696,0.41313378580273563,0.5885279250471613,0.42327152145578684,0.6634368740862532,0.4333441499662122,0.21659748102099396,0.26648139608440125,0.8286608665013249,0.597317060339539,0.016019599035111964,0.0705188294495055,0.29618333976099265,0.026844347303026594,0.4116081938965338,0.6706042266243082,0.055089623581153324,0.1326727164796469,0.08983761767503162,0.06030867763034692,0.39410268780631413,0.27944060253310304,0.6084770378056369,0.8824760005195302,0.8015744871238857,0.8449398171576914,0.6444966774784043,0.840244477105099,0.053895997569592846,0.17871782924049612,0.4629208568879122,0.26595887249103733,0.909474881302015,0.8905111975366351,0.09313318169150014,0.3273028785695412,0.06136013851659888,0.28186910832415546,0.04724975914109447,0.18438226297890514,0.4953824474130914,0.5545711313453364,0.07749246934059112,0.3166129929826957,0.13189624401497602,0.06763941090423253,0.07277849551627152,0.13581753410278663,0.1892358783372411,0.19516156039393595,0.34958390444996923,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,808,en,0.6691603888068514,0.718814464768232,0.5661652815880605,0.4601827701072446,0.6166793213059706,0.6795867244262861,0.5788861651935705,0.5914968841883378,0.6553881292052748,0.5523725286708736,0.6649348486332591,0.42393001884587933,0.5005358549523916,0.734270322413669,0.46491210407409866,0.5289476364930752,0.6661335771899513,0.5645313582350592,0.5563771592912468,0.493192131792016,0.3735446850308613,0.4522219878578576,0.5037515144587645,0.6128900730244894,0.5236500108020969,0.5331561254757491,0.6001216543569639,0.491227128455882,0.7804337208548147,0.4476202642846683,0.6187379580913436,0.6444003962346634,0.7038106937262903,0.6691571737389863,0.5781423836259865,0.6869979888559247,0.6697944559470006,0.6935773545916478,0.7153004643921403,0.6173573642387694,0.7058252549695404,0.695764916693818,0.73793838705737,0.7302370485663638,0.804091031989747,0.5964380108081452,0.7576832799525879,0.5998835971727043,0.6679473068205258,0.7503066610900953,0.668643110066251,0.8266644773617418,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true
```

In this respone I can not see 516 id.

Comment: "I want to store information about the id of the," ??

Comment: @JakeJ sorry, I fixed it!

Comment: Are you passing each user individually to Watson, or the whole dataset?  I bet it processes the whole batch and just gives the average for each when you pass a whole dataset.

Comment: And if you're passing it per user, then you can just grab the id since you already have it.

Comment: Sorry, last comment, based on what I've learned so far with neural nets / deep learning, it's highly unlikely that they're going to pass back IDs.  You'll get back what they've trained it to recognize, in this case emotion values to words.